# How to force angular refresh layout?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an html page that looks like this (left side, right side content with those squares, received from a designer)

[image]

if I go in html and add more squares they will automatically adjust to the available width and create a new row when needed when page is loaded.

Now, I need the squares to be dynamic, so I have an array in my controller

```
$scope.tickers = [];
```

which i populate in a method .

```
$scope.add = function(){
            $scope.tickers.push(
                {name: 'AAA', dir:'up', price: '890'}
            );
        }
```

And here the problem arise, anytime the squares don't fit in the available width, they do move under the left side menu bar and won't create a new row.
See image

[image]

Now if I just resize a little the browser window they will arrange as needed (as in picture 1). 
The html code looks like this

```
<div class="bsBlock">
    <div class="buy_block lft" ng-repeat="t in tickers">
        <h3>{{t.name}}</h3>

        <span><i class="{{t.dir}}"></i><em>{{t.price | currency}}</em></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for the angular somehow force layout refresh so a new row would be created when needed?

thx

Comment: I don't think it;s an Angular problem. Sounds more like a CSS/layout issue. Could you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Agree with ExperSystem, I would make a test using Bootstrap and playing with row / span you could get the desired behavior, could you create a plunkr / jsfiddle? We can play with that until we get the desired behavior.